# "Can not merge type error" when converting Pandas dataframe to Spark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

panda_df:

| Column | DataType |
| --- | --- |
| OrganizationID | Int64 |
| Name | object |
| OrgCode | Int64 |
| StartDate | datetime64[ns] |
| EndDate | datetime64[ns] |
| ApplicationID | Int64 |

panda_df  have  ,NaT and nan values.

`spark_df=spark.createDataFrame(panda_df)`

when converting to the Spark dataframe getting  -

`TypeError: field ApplicationID: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StructType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'>`

How to handle the ,NaT and nan values and get the Int data type instead of LongType.